# NameError: name '_' is not defined (python, phonenumbers)

Tags: python, django

как убрать ошибку `NameError: name '_' is not defined`?

**models.py**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import phonenumbers

def validate_phone_number(value):
    try:
        z = phonenumbers.parse(value, None)
    except phonenumbers.NumberParseException:
        raise ValidationError(_('%(value) is not a valid phone number'), params={'value': value},)
    if not phonenumbers.is_valid_number(z):
        raise ValidationError(_('%(value) is not a valid phone number'),params={'value': value},)

class Storehouses(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[validate_phone_number], unique=True, max_length=17, verbose_name='Телефон')
```

Comment: `from django.utils.translation import gettext as _`  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли импортировать библиотеку **django.utils.translation**, а именно её модуль **gettext**.

Для этого следует прописать в начале следующее:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
```

Подробности о **gettext()** модуле вы можете прочитать [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/)

Надеюсь, мой ответ вам поможет!

Answer (score 2):

***Импорт забыли***

Добавьте `from django.utils.translation import gettext as _`. Об этом написано [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/)